# How to get only part of path from @Path?

Tags: java, web-services, url, path, uri

From the path ("/api/webservice/cursos/sugeridos/java-para-desenvolvimento-web") I need to get ("/api/webservice/cursos/").

I have the class:

```
@Path("/webservice/cursos")
public class Resource {

@GET
    @Path("/sugeridos/{uri: [\\w+\\-]*}")
    .........
    public Response getCourseByURI(@PathParam("uri") String uri, @Context UriInfo uriInfo) {
                String baseUrl = uriInfo.getAbsolutePath().getPath();
     }
}
```

The `uriInfo.getAbsolutePath().getPath()` returns:

> "/api/webservice/cursos/sugeridos/java-para-desenvolvimento-web"

I need only:

> "/api/webservice/cursos/"

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this:

```
String pathInfo = request.getPathInfo(); // //api/webservice/cursos/sugeridos/java-para-desenvolvimento-web
String[] parts = pathInfo.split("/");
String part0 = parts[0]; // api
String part1 = parts[1]; // webservice
String part2 = parts[2]; // cursos
```

Get the request in the `HttpServletRequest`.

Answer (score 0):

You can use java-7 [`Path`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/nio/file/Path.html#subpath(int,%20int)) class:

```
Path path = Paths.get("/api/webservice/cursos/sugeridos/java-para-desenvolvimento-web");
System.out.println(path.subpath(0,3)); // api/webservice/cursos
```